# Multivariable Calculus Word Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I solve the following problem. I'm not sure what it falls under so I don't know where to look in the book for help....

> Find the three positive number with product 27 which **minimizes the
>   sum** of the third with twice the second with four times the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** So we want to minimize $4x+2y+z$ subject to the condition that $x$, $y$. and $z$ are positive and $xyz=27$.

If you have already seen [*Lagrange Multipliers*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) this is a good place to use the method. If you have not, see the alternate approach below. Let
$$F(x,y,z,\lambda)=4x+2y+z+\lambda(xyz-27),$$
and set the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to $x$, $y$, $z$, and $\lambda$ equal to $0$. Solve and see what this tells you. You will need to check that there really is a *minimum* at the point you find.

**Another way:**  We have $z=\frac{27}{xy}$. So we want to minimize $G(x,y)$, where 
$$G(x,y)=4x+2y+\frac{27}{xy}.$$
Calculate the partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, and set them equal to $0$. Solve. Then you have to show that we really do get a *minimum*.

**Remark:** You are doing this for a calculus course, so I have suggested  calculus ways. But there is (in my opinion) a nicer way. Let $u=4x$, $v=2y$, and $w=z$. We want to minimize $u+v+w$ subject to the condition that the variables are positive, and $uvw=(27)(8)$.

By the Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality (known affectionately as AM-GM to generations of Math Olympiad contestants) we have
$$\frac{u+v+w}{3}\ge (uvw)^{1/3},$$
with equality only when $u=v=w$.

So $\frac{u+v+w}{3}\ge 6$, with equality when $u=v=w$. That gives minimum value of $u+v+w$ equal to $18$. Putting $u=v=w$ we find that each is equal to $6$, so our minimum is reached at $x=\frac{3}{2}$, $y=3$, and $z=6$.

The above remark is intended to show that calculus is not the only tool for such problems. It will also serve as a check for your Lagrange Multiplier (or other) calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a constrained optimization problem.  Let's call the 3 numbers $x,y,z$.  Your objective is to minimize:

$$
f(x,y,z)=4x+2y+z
$$

subject to the constraint:

$$
g(x,y,z)=xyz=27
$$

To solve the problem, use Lagrange multipliers:

$$
\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda(g(x,y,z)-27)
$$
So we require $\nabla\mathcal{L}=0$:

$$
4=\lambda yz\\
2=\lambda xz\\
1=\lambda xy\\
xyz=27
$$

You can solve for the unknowns $x,y,z$.  If you obtain multiple answers, choose the positive ones.